# custom front end form submit in theme function.php

Tags: wordpress, forms, submission

I want to create custom front end form and submit data on that form as post in wp_post table. But I want to do functionality into theme not as a plugin. I m using wpestate theme from themeforest.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the wp_insert_post() function [is well documented](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)

so:

1. Create a form
2. Create submit code
3. If all its ok create a post

After you create the post you can add meta data this way:

```
$new_post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_args, false);


if($new_post_id != 0){
  //add all data you want
  add_post_meta($new_post_id, 'your_key', 'your_value', false);
}
```

What happens here is that if everything its ok $new_post_id should store the id of the new post you just to create, with that id you can now store meta data.

[Check this good tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/posting-via-the-front-end-inserting--wp-27034)

Comment: where do I add custom form field data?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use wp_insert_post function for insert post data and for remaining information you can add information in post meta table,

```
update_post_meta($post_id,'meta-key')
```

Try to use link i think this will provide help

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103442/front-end-posting